# How To Install GCC On Cygwin

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

So this C/Python book that I own says to choose gcc, gcc-core and gcc-g++ on the Select Packages window. But I couldn't find any such on the list, so I searched up gcc and selected all these from here, as shown in the picture.

[My Select Packages Window with my selections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozr3P.png)

Finished Installing. Then went to Cygwin and typed in gcc version. It says not found.

[Says Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvOrp.png)

What should I do? Is it because of my version 2.905 as opposed to the book's version of 2.769? Please help.

Comment: why Cygwin and not WSL?

Comment: "Says not found" ... you didn't give any parameters to gcc.

Comment: The different version is not much off and shouldn't matter for a beginner.

Comment: The command to get the version of gcc is `gcc --version`.

Comment: @Swordfish yes I tried both gcc--version and gcc version. And what parameter should I give? Should I use WSL instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it installed, but you are misunderstanding the usage

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

In this way, you are saying the compiler to compile a file called `version`

```
$ gcc version
gcc: error: version: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

that gcc can not find, so it reports an error.
You can also check if a program is available and where is with `type`

```
$ type gcc
gcc is hashed (/usr/bin/gcc)

$ type g++
g++ is /usr/bin/g++
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. The book said gcc--version and not gcc --version. This fixed it for me.

Comment: sometime the  space are difficult to recognize due to font compacting.

Comment: That's why _we_ (tech people) prefere monospaced fonts https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font